# c++ Access elements of an object in a vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a vector of `MyClass` created pretty much in this way:

```
class MyClass {
    friend Class MyOtherClass;

public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass()

    // some functions...

private:
    MyOtherClass other;
    std::string hgnc_symbol;
    uint_64 start_p;
    uint_64 stop_p;
    int objID;
    std::vector<MyClass> list;
};
```

I'm really having hard time with the iterator, as I can't figure out how to properly access the filed of the objects stored in the vector.

I populate the `list` reading elements from a file. And everything is OK, because `list.size()` returns the right number of elements. When I want to retrieve an object by its `objID`, I use an iterator to iterate over the list's objects. This is the code i've been trying

```
MyClass getByID(int id) {
    std::vector<MyClass>::iterator it;
    for(it=list.begin(); it!=list.end(); ++it){
        if((*it)->objID == id) {
            std::cout << "FOUND! " << (*it)->objID << "\n";
            return (*it);
        }
    }
}
```

but in this case, the field `objID` *cannot be resolved*. Trying with

```
...
if((*it).objID == id) 
std::cout << "ID = " << (*it).objID << "";
...
```

the field is resolved but it prints thousands of `ID = 0` as if all the objects added to the list were empty.

Shall I create a vector of pointers to object (like `std::vector<MyClass*> list;`)? would it be of any help? I actually tried but nothing changes: still I can't access the fields of each object, even though the iterators returns the pointer to it.

Comment: It would be easier if you could post a real but minimal code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Omit the default constructor declaration/definition to have the default constructor, copy constructor, assignment operator generated by the compiler for you.

Comment: With `std::vector<MyClass>::iterator it;` to access a member of `MyClass` using that iterator (when the iterator is valid) would look like `it->objID` or `(*it).objID`. Writing `(*it)->objID` is likely to be a compiler error and is not what you want. As the question is written there is not enough information for us to determine why `(*it).objID` will always result in `objID == 0`. Perhaps check to make sure you are actually setting `objID` to a valid value somewhere.

Comment: Are you sure you want your MyClass class to have a vector of its own type as a member?

Comment: @arayq2 what do you mean? shall I move it outside the class and make it global? I actually thought about this, but I could not see any improvement in doing that. Why would you suggest it?

Comment: Recursive structures can be problematic unless you're implementing recursive algorithms, that's all.  If you have your reasons, that's fine.  But besides that, what value do you propose to return if the Id is not found?

Comment: @arayq2 Just dealing with that issue. I think I better change to `MyClass *getByID(int id)` and return NULL

Comment: That isn't the end of your semantic problems.  std::vector has value semantics: so you will have trouble storing any kind of state in your MyClass instances.  Are you sure you want that too?

Comment: @arayq2 I do understand your point. But the fact is, the searched-by-ID value may not exist, in which case either I throw and handle exceptions, or I just return a NULL pointer. As far as I know, there is no way to return a NULL reference in C++

Comment: Another option, which is the one I've been using, is to return a `new MyClass()` object with default values (the constructor is actually more detailed than the one in the snippet above). In this way I'll have the chance to later wipe out the vector. in fact, I feel it is not an elegant programming solution at all, but it's the one I've found so far

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider using an `std::map` for this instead, saving your objects using the `objID` as the key:

```
std::map<int, MyClass> objects;
objects.insert(std::make_pair(objId, MyClass));

// later.. do what you want with the data by simply using:

objects.at(someID) ...
```

As you can see, this handles all of the iteration / looping for you, and could potentially make your code cleaner. Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/) if you're interested.

Comment: actually, `objID` doesn't act as a key since it is not unique. Also, most of the operations on the list's objects will deal with the `start` and `stop` fields: Searching and ordering the list according to these two fields, mostly. Thus I believe a vector would be the easiest choice. But I might be wrong